# Добавлять в строку пробел через определенное кол-во символов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим у нас есть строка:

> "ааааааааааааааааааааааааа"

В ней 24 символа, как сделать что бы если строка > 24 и у нее идут подряд 24 символа без пробела то после каждого 24 символа, ставить пробел и на выходе получалось:

```
text = "аааааааааааааааааааааааааaa" #len (26)
OUT: "ааааааааааааааааааааааааа aa"
```

Отмечу что текст может быть и не такой длины, а куда больше.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно попробовать через регулярку:

```
import re

text = "аааааааааааааааааааааааааaaааааааааааа ааааааааааааааaa"
new_text = re.sub('([^ ]{24})', r'\1 ', text)
new_text = new_text.replace('  ', ' ')
print(new_text)
# аааааааааааааааааааааааа аaaааааааааааа ааааааааааааааaa
```

Comment: @Cookie правда, тут не учитывается, что 25 символ может уже быть пробелом, поэтому в строке может стать 2 пробела подряд. Обновил ответ

Comment: тоже заметил при проверке) Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

если нужно много пробелов

```
text = "аааааааасссссссаааааааааааааааааbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaa"

res = ' '.join([text[i:i+24] for i in range(0, len(text), 24)]) if ' ' not in text[:24] and len(text) > 24 else text

print(res)
```

если нужен только 1 пробел

```
text = "аааааааааааааааааааааааааaa"

res = f'{text[:24]} {text[25:]}' if ' ' not in text[:24] and len(text) > 24 else text

print(res)
```

Comment: добавляет только один пробел после первых 24 символов. А "текст может быть и не такой длинны, а куда больше". Например "аааааааасссссссаааааааааааааааааbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaa"

Comment: я просто из условий не понял - надо 1 проблем, надо каждые 24 символа или каждые 24 символа при сохранении условия

Comment: @Эникейщик, добавил соответствующий код, правда если имеется в виду что пробел надо добавлять ТОЛЬКО ТОГДА, когда каждые 24 символа нет пробела - тогда конечно иной код нужен

Answer (score 5):

```
import textwrap

text = 'аааааааааааааааааааааааааaa   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
result = ' '.join(' '.join(textwrap.wrap(word, 24)) for word in text.split(' '))
print(result) # аааааааааааааааааааааааа аaa   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbb
```

С регулярками

```
import re

text = 'аааааааааааааааааааааааааaa   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb'
result = re.sub('(\S{24})(?=\S)', r'\1 ', text)
print(result) # аааааааааааааааааааааааа аaa   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbb
```

Comment: @Эникейщик пример? я ведь специально поделил со `split(' ')` а не `split()`. А, ну да, вижу

Comment: А, не. Я обсчитался.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да нет, проблема правда была. Исправил. Просто `textwrap.wrap('')` неожиданно дает пустой список.

Answer (score 2):

```
pprint = lambda x: " ".join(x[i: i + 24] for i in range(0, len(x), 24))

print(" ".join(pprint(el) for el in x.split()))
```

Comment: А тут будет учитываться, что в кусках по 24 символа не будет пробела?